Which is better exercise?

Which is better exercise?

What is the subject of the sentence?
Which or better exercise?
Or Both of them are possible?

Does it matter?  English doesn't mark the subject in any way in this case.  What difference would it make to your understanding of the question?  A slightly more interesting example would be to identify the subject in the sentence "Who am I?"

In "Who am I?", the subject is "I". cf) "Who are you?", "You" is a subject. We use 'to be' verb according to the subject: I am, You are.

Which is the subject.
I think "better exercise" is called a subject complement, but that might not be correct.

I would write this way:

Which is [the] better exercise?

Which is the subject.
The better exercise is called subject complement or predicate nominative.  It redefines the subject which.

So why is it "Who am I" and not "Who am me" or "Whom am I" or "Who is me" etc?

Hi, @James K,  Copulas are intransitive and hence don’t take objects.  The subject complements hence have the same case as the subject, as in Who am I.   Whom am I won’t work in this way but would work as part of a question in the formal To whom am I speaking? (Who am I speaking to? is more common.)
Who is me doesn’t work.

But "It is me" is also correct.

Hi, @James K, Yes, It’s me is the idiomatic one.  The grammatical It’s I isn’t.
I remember one post some four years back about someone knocking on the door, and the OP asked which version to use.  I said use the grammatical one.  Now I think except in formal context, most people would choose the idiomatic one.  Grammaticality doesn’t mean idiomacy.

I would disagree.  The correct grammar in modern English is "It's me".  (compare French "C'est moi"  the "It is I" form is a hypercorrect construction, from the Anglo-saxon, or perhaps Latin.

Hi, @James K, okay, noted.  Now I have a problem trying to reconcile this with that which says noun type subject complements are to be in the subject case.

The rules aren't clear and often you can use either. For example, you could say either "Which one is him?" or "Which one is he?" (e.g. if looking at a photo). Grammarians may claim to know one of those is correct, but I think either would be OK.

Thank, @Stuart F.  Yes.  The language is dynamic and adjusts over time.
